# How to make add queries to new sheets depending on the name? On VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering how I would go about making a macros which reads off a list of specific URL variables and makes a data query and a new sheet for a different name.

For example in my url tab I have this:

```
Dan     Butler      2017
Dan     Butler      2018
Jack    Riewoldt    2007
Jack    Riewoldt    2008
Jack    Riewoldt    2009
Jack    Riewoldt    2010
Jack    Riewoldt    2011
Jack    Riewoldt    2012
Jack    Riewoldt    2013
Jack    Riewoldt    2014
Jack    Riewoldt    2015
Jack    Riewoldt    2016
Jack    Riewoldt    2017
Jack    Riewoldt    2018
```

The URL I have is this: [http://www.fanfooty.com.au/players/year.php?firstname=**Dylan**&surname=**Grimes**&year=**2018**](http://www.fanfooty.com.au/players/year.php?firstname=Dylan&surname=Grimes&year=2018)

As you can see the only variables are the first and last name and the year.

I want it so the macro will make a new sheet for each new name and add tables to that sheet for each year. It should only make a new sheet for each new name it encounters.

What I currently have is this:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim URL As Range
For Each URL In Range("a200:a211").Cells
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.fanfooty.com.au/players/year.phpfirstname=Shaun&surname=Grigg&year=" & URL & "" _
        , Destination:=Range("$a$5"))
        .Name = "Shaun Grigg"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = "1"
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        Range("R:S").EntireColumn.Insert
    End With
Next
End sub
```

So far the only thing I could get is one sheet and getting all the tables for a player to appear, but I cannot do multiple players at once with one macro.

And the way I get different players is to manually add a sheet and adjust the url myself.

Thanks guys

Comment: Don't post code as image, post as text and format as code. Many of us can't open external links and they may break over time. Also, it's hard to try your code as it is, as text we can copy and paste to try to help you.

Comment: And what is your actual question? Where did you get stuck or errors? What does already work and what does not?

Comment: Sorry guys, i have made the edits, i am new to this forum so dont get how the formatting works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use a separate procedure which adds one sheet at once and fill it with data. Then a second procedure loops through the data.

`AddConnection` adds a new sheet with the data loaded from the given parameters.

`GetAllUrls` loops through the data and calls `AddConnection`.

You would probably need to adjust the `For` loops to your needs and data source if your data is not in `A1:C14` but I think the principle is clear.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetAllUrls()
    Dim wsURL As Worksheet
    Set wsURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("URL") 'here we define the urls worksheet

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 14 'we assume the data is in A1 to C14 (A=name, B=surname, C=year)
        AddConnection wsURL.Cells(i, 1), wsURL.Cells(i, 2), wsURL.Cells(i, 3)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub AddConnection(Name, Surname, Year)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.add(After:=ActiveSheet) 'add a new sheet
    ws.Name = Left(Name & " " & Surname & " " & Year, 31) 'rename sheet (sheet names must be max 31 characters)

    With ws.QueryTables.add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.fanfooty.com.au/players/year.php?firstname=" & Name & "&surname=" & Surname & "&year=" & Year _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = Name & " " & Surname & " " & Year
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I will give it a go and let you know how it works

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I just gave it a go and it worked well. However, is there a way to make it so that each tab is just one player and all their yearly tables are on the same sheet. For example in one sheet called "Dan Butler" we have his 2017 stats and 2018 stats side by side, then the macro will make a Jack Riewoldt sheet with his stats from 2007-18 in the sheet.

Comment: @user9198458 this would me much more to code and is to broad to answer here. It would be possible but a completely new approach. If this answer solved your original question please consider marking it as a solution.

Comment: thanks for your help, would you have any idea on how i could get started on that? Yep answered part of it defitnetly and was the most helpful here, just couldnt get it exactly the way i wanted